Ошибка при подключении к БД (PostgreSQL), запущенной через Docker Compose
Не могу подключится к БД (PostgreSQL), запущенной через Docker Compose.
docker compose:
version: '3.9'

services:

pg:
 image: postgres
 container_name: postgresqldb
 restart: always
 environment:
  POSTGRES_DB: users
  POSTGRES_USER: user
  POSTGRES_PASSWORD: mysecurepass
 ports:
   - "5432:5432"

Подключаюсь через DataGrip в PyCharm:

При попытке подключиться вылазит ошибка:
[28P01] �����: ������������ "user" �� ������ �������� ����������� (�� ������).

Скрин ошибки:

Думал, что роли user просто не существует, но она есть:


В docker-compose.yml база называется users, а в DataGrip вы подключаетесь к базе postgres

Проверьте pg_hba.conf, есть ли у пользователя нужные разрешения.
Еще можно посмотреть что postgres пишет через

docker logs

И дополнительно, вы действительно не к той бд подключаетесь, как написали выше.

добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]
